# How to prevent a numbered list when starting a paragraph with "1."?

Tags: support, markdown, list

I just stumbled upon [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/revisions/18962/2) on Chess Stack Exchange, where it looks like the author wanted to start a paragraph with "1. Nxc6" (which is the common notation for a chess move) but did not want a numbered list to appear, which automatically happens if you start a paragraph with a number followed by a dot, like this:

1. Nxc6 gets the two Bishops in a position

---

I was able to solve it by introducing an HTML comment like this:

```
<!-->
1. Nxc6 gets the two Bishops in a position
```

which produces

1. Nxc6 gets the two Bishops in a position

but I feel this is a rather inelegant solution. Are there any other/better options, preferably within pure Markdown?